# Elements of two dimensional array taking enter as value

Tags: arrays, pascal

I have simple program with only assignment to read elements of two dimensional array which are inputed in n rows by m elements in pascal.. Only two elements that are typed in are '.' and '#'.

```
Program test;
Type matrica=array[1..20,1..25] of char;
Var A:matrica; n,m,j,i:integer;
Begin
n:=4;
m:=5;
For i:=1 to n do
  For j:=1 to m do
  Read(A[i,j]);
End.
```

What i have noticed while inputing and converting with ord and char to see what are exact elements is this:
-If i input all 20 elements at once, array is fine;
-But, If i input less elements at a time:e.g. ony by one; Its like this A[1,1]=.; A[1,2]= ;A[1,3]= ;   From char function i found out that A[1,2] is taking value 13 and A[1,3] value 10. Internet says that `A[char(13),char(10)]` is same as `Writeln`. But why is pascal taking enter as value for my array?

Comment: `13` and `10` are the carriage return and line feed, respectively. See the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) for reference. In other words, Pascal also is reading the "enter" key when you press it.

Comment: Thats so lame :/ now when user enters five elements and hit enter my program is going to fail... I'll have to rewrite it, thank you for answering

Comment: Well... it's not really lame. That's how software works. The Enter key has an ASCII representation just like any other characters. Your program needs to take that into account since you're reading input a character at a time. Just decide how you want to handle them now that you know they occur and write your program accordingly. If you need to read a character at a time, you can ignore the enter codes just by checking for them, e.g., `read(c); if c <> #10 and c <> #13 then ....` Or you can check for displayable ASCII: `if c in [32..126] then...`.